# Phrase for the idea that we experience life as a narrative and contribute to it?

Tags: expressions

There is [this poem by Whitman](http://www.poetryfoundation.org/poem/182088) who paints a picture of life as a narrative that we contribute our story to:

> **O Me! O Life!**
>
> Oh me! Oh life! of the questions of these recurring,
>
> Of the endless trains of the faithless, of cities fill’d with the foolish,
>
> Of myself forever reproaching myself, (for who more foolish than I, and who more faithless?)
>
> Of eyes that vainly crave the light, of the objects mean, of the struggle ever renew’d,
>
> Of the poor results of all, of the plodding and sordid crowds I see around me,
>
> Of the empty and useless years of the rest, with the rest me intertwined,
>
> The question, O me! so sad, recurring—What good amid these, O me, O life?
>
> *Answer.*
>
> That you are here—that life exists and identity,
>
> That the powerful play goes on, and you may contribute a verse.

My question is - **is there a phrase that describes this idea of life as a narrative?** (My guess is 'hi-story'. )

Comment: Apropos of [Apple's ad](http://www.apple.com/your-verse/#video-your-verse), perhaps?

Comment: Love it; but almost uniquely among tech companies, Apple does live at the intersection of Technology and Liberal Arts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Narrative Paradigm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narrative_paradigm)

The Narrative Paradigm is a theory proposed by Walter Fisher that all meaningful communication is a form of storytelling or giving a report of events, and that human beings experience and comprehend life as a series of ongoing narratives, each with its own conflicts, characters, beginning, middle, and end.

[Existentialism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existentialism)

a chiefly 20th century philosophical movement embracing diverse doctrines but centering on analysis of individual existence in an unfathomable universe and the plight of the individual who must assume ultimate responsibility for acts of free will without any certain knowledge of what is right or wrong or good or bad.

Answer (score 0):

"All the world's a stage" which begin Shakespeare's [As You Like It](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/asyoulikeit/full.html),

> All the world's a stage,
>
> And all the men and women merely players:
>
> They have their exits and their entrances;
>
> And one man in his time plays many parts,